# How can I sort for the largest value in c++?

Tags: c++, sorting

I want to print out just the name and his highest batting average. I've tried for loop but it doesn't sort anything, it just reprints the average of each player. I've tried double average[10] and it just returns the memory address. I need your advices.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// Structure to hold batting statistics
struct  Player
{
    string name;
    double atBats;
    double hits;
    double average;
};

int main()
{
    ifstream statFile;
    string playerName;
    double bats, hits;
    Player* baseballArray[100];
    Player* aPlayer;
    int numPlayers = 0;
    double largest = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    statFile.open("stats.txt");

    // Continue reading until the end of file
    while (statFile >> playerName)
    {
        statFile >> bats >> hits;

        // Dynamically create a new Player
        aPlayer = new Player;
        aPlayer->name = playerName;
        aPlayer->atBats = bats;
        aPlayer->hits = hits;
        aPlayer->average = aPlayer->hits / aPlayer->atBats;
        // Store the pointer to the Player struct in the array
        baseballArray[numPlayers++] = aPlayer;

        largest = aPlayer->average;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            temp = aPlayer->average;
            if (temp > largest)
                largest = temp;
        }

        // Display this information
        cout << aPlayer->name << " has " << aPlayer->atBats << " at bats and "
            << aPlayer->hits << " hits with " << aPlayer->average << " batting average." <<  endl;

        cout << aPlayer->name << " has the highest batting average with " << largest << endl;

    }
```

Comment: @Eljay `baseballArray` is initialized in the main loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always modifying `largest`, regardless of the actual value.  Also, the inner for-loop does absolutely nothing.  You're also outputting the "highest average" player inside your main loop.

If you want to track the player with highest average during input, just store a pointer or an array index:

```
Player* highestAveragePlayer = NULL;

while(numPlayers < 100 && statFile >> playerName >> bats >> hits)
{
    Player* aPlayer = new Player;
    aPlayer->name = playerName;
    aPlayer->atBats = bats;
    aPlayer->hits = hits;
    aPlayer->average = aPlayer->hits / aPlayer->atBats;
    baseballArray[numPlayers++] = aPlayer;

    // Update player with highest average
    if (!highestAveragePlayer || aPlayer->average > highestAveragePlayer->average)
        highestAveragePlayer = aPlayer;
}

// Output AFTER the loop
if (highestAveragePlayer)
{
    cout << highestAveragePlayer->name << " has the highest batting average with "
         << highestAveragePlayer->average << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, instead of computing this inside the loop, you can just search your player array afterwards with something like `std::max_element` from `<algorithm>`:

```
if (numPlayers > 0)
{
    Player** pIter = std::max_element(baseballArray, baseballArray+numPlayers,
        [](const Player* &a, const Player* &b) {
            return a->average < b->average;
        });
    cout << (*pIter)->name << " has the highest batting average with "
         << (*pIter)->average << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can I have an idea how to show both the largest and secondlargest values?

Comment: Really?  You store a pointer for "second-highest", of course.  Your tests inside the loop become slightly more complex, as you need to check for first-time encounter and then correctly manage the two highest values.  Alternatively, you can call `max_element`, then remove the highest one (or temporarily set its average to zero) and call `max_element` a second time.  Or you can sort the entire array and then choose the last two (or first two, if sorting in reverse).